# how to access processing.js variable from javaskript and change it

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

in the processing sketch i got

```
int posX = 10; 
int posY = 10;
int s = 12;
int vx,vy;
int red,gr,bl, =0;

void setup(){
    size(200,200);
    vx = random(6);
    vy = random(6);
}

void draw(){
    if(mousePressed){
    red = r;
    gr = g;
    bl = b;
    }
    background(red,gr,bl);
    fill(255);
    posX += vx ;
    posY += vy ;

    if (posX > width || posX<0){
        vx *= -1;
    }
    if(posY > height || posY < 0){
        vy *= -1;
    }
    ellipse (posX,posY,s,s);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <script src="processing-1.4.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="msg">
     </div>
     <canvas id = "canvas" data-processing-sources="mixing.pde"></canvas>
     <button onclick = "startSketch();">Start</button>
     <button onclick = "stopSketch();">Stop</button>
     <script type="application/javascript">
         var processingInstance;
         sp = 1;

         function startSketch(){
            switchSketchState(true);
         }

         function stopSketch(){
            switchSketchState(false);
         }


         function switchSketchState(on){
            if(!processingInstance){
                processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById('canvas');
            }

            if (on){
                processingInstance.loop();
            }
            else{
                processingInstance.noLoop();
            }
            alert(processingInstance.posX);// this return undefined i have to see 10
         }
     </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and when i am trying to access posX variable via javascript and alert it on the screen like that the browser tell me that it is undefined. Is there any way to access variables and change their values.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] or a fiddle? When are you executing your JavaScript? Are you sure it happens after your Processing code is loaded?

Comment: it is a normal HTML document after my canvas i got two buttons one to start `loop()` and one who stop animation with `Noloop()` after them i got my javascript code and i am pretty shore that my code is loaded because i animate ball to moove across the canvas and i start and stop animation via buttons

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to help you without seeing a [mcve] that we can run, or a JSFiddle that we can play with.

Comment: It is not nessesery to be in that particular example i just need a way ot access avariable from javascript to processing and to be able to read and write that variable if it is posible.

Comment: The code you posted looks okay, but it's not really enough to really answer you. We need to see more code- specifically code that we can run, either as a [mcve] or a JSFiddle.

Comment: i hope this would be enough

Comment: Yep, thanks for that. I've tracked down your problem and posted an answer. Let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sketch has a couple logic problems: you're switching between `int` and `float` types, and you're using undefined variables `r` `g` and `b`.

I highly recommend programming in Java mode so that these errors are more obvious, then switching to JavaScript mode when you're ready to deploy.

But your real problem is this: **Processing.js only gives you access to a sketch's functions, not its variables.**

If you want to get `posX` in JavaScript, you're going to have to write a `getPosX()` function and then call that from JavaScript.

Same thing if you want to set it: create a `setPosX()` function and then call that.

Comment: i use r,g,b variables in my test "thing" i just forgot to erase them when i post the example it works that way i made a function for positionX and i call it

Comment: @Mimi Nice. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it logs a processing variable in js on line 67

```html
 <!-- 

from:
http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html

with added function getX(); to demonstrate how to pass variables from a processing sketch to javascript

-->
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Hello Web - Controlling Processing from JavaScript</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">
int x=y=1;
int xVel=yVel=3;
int t = 300;
  
void setup() {
  size(310, 200);
  background(100);
  stroke(255);
  println('hello web!');
}
  
int getX() {
  return t;
}
  
void draw(){
  ellipse(x, y,10,10);
  x = x + xVel;
  y = y + yVel;
  if ((x > width)||(x < 0)){
    xVel = xVel * -1;
  }
  if ((y > height)||(y < 0)){
    yVel = yVel * -1;
  }
}
</script>
        <button onclick="startSketch();">
         Start</button>
     <button onclick="stopSketch();">
         Stop</button>
     <canvas id="pjs" data-processing-sources="pjs"</canvas>

     <script type="application/javascript">
         var processingInstance;
 
         function startSketch() {
             switchSketchState(true);
         }
 
         function stopSketch() {
             switchSketchState(false);
         }
 
         function switchSketchState(on) {
             if (!processingInstance) {
                 processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById('pjs');
             }
 
             if (on) {
                 processingInstance.loop();
                 console.log(processingInstance.getX());
             } else {
                 processingInstance.noLoop(); // stop animation, call noLoop()
             }
         }
     </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

working example:

https://codepen.io/madmaker/pen/QZddLR